# angular autocomplete with filter in form array in reactive forms

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material2, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem, how to create one filtered autocomplete list and use it in different form array controls.

My form model:

```
 this.prodForm = this.fb.group({
            date: ['', Validators.required],
            priority: ['', Validators.required],
            products: this.fb.array([])
        });

 var product = this.fb.group({
        name: '',
        isTrial: '',
    })
```

Autocomplete list:

```
this.filteredMachineProducts = this.productCtrl.valueChanges.
        startWith(null).
        map(name => this.filterMachineProducts(name));

 filterMachineProducts(val: string) {
    return val ? this.machineProducts.filter((s) => s.name.match(new RegExp(val, 'gi'))) : this.machineProducts;
}
```

And front:

```
<div formArrayName="products">
  <div *ngFor="let product of products.controls; let p=index" [formGroupName]="p">
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Produkt #{{p + 1}}
          <mat-panel-description>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="removeProduct(p)">Usuń</button>
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
        <div fxFlex.gt-sm="25" fxFlex.gt-xs="50" fxFlex="100">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Asortyment" [matAutocomplete]="productAutoComplete" [formControl]="productCtrl">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-autocomplete #productAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let machineProduct of filteredMachineProducts | async" [value]="machineProduct" (onSelectionChange)="getProductMachine(machineProduct, p)">
              <span>{{ machineProduct.name }}</span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </div>
```

At this moment I use separate formControl but it should be formControlName="name".

Should I create filtered list for each autocomplete in loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to create a filtered list for each auto-complete.

I have answered a question of this sort [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562889/10121188).