# How to add Angular Material auto complete in FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am using Angular 6. My form has a `formArray` to which I Add Items on a button click.
My form looks like

```js
private initForm() {
  this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
    'orderItems': this.orderItems,
    'customerContact': new FormControl(null),
    'totalAmount': new FormControl(null)
  });
}

onAddItem() {
  (<FormArray>this.orderForm.get('orderItems')).push(
    new FormGroup({
      'itemName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'itemService': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'itemPrice': new FormControl(null)
    })
  );
}
```

Html code

```html
<tbody formArrayName="orderItems">
  <tr *ngFor="let orderItem of getControls(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
      <input type="text" formControlName="itemName" class="form-control" [matAutocomplete]="autoName">
      <mat-autocomplete #autoName="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOrderItems | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" formControlName="itemService" class="form-control" [matAutocomplete]="autoService">
      <mat-autocomplete #autoService="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOrderServices | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="itemPrice" (keyup)="findTotal()">
      <!-- </mat-form-field> -->
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteIngredient(i)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Autocomplete on fileds `itemName` and `itemService` is not working. I am not able to apply filter to these fields. I am open to suggestions even if I am able to achieve this by changing some functionality of the form.
Here is the part of the application [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yy8bc)

Comment: Lots of important code is missing - getControls(), orderItems, how onAddItem() is triggered... It would be best if you created a working stackblitz example for us to work with, and post all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to relate each `control` inside the `FormArray` to its own `filteredOrderItems` array.
I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562889/10121188), please read the answer details and take a look at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szxkme?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts) reproduction.

please feel free to ask.
Thanks

Comment: Thank a lot, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: you are welcome, I'm happy this is the first time someone marks my answer as correct ^_^

Answer (score 0):

@Mukul Jaggi  you can install `angular animation`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-add-angular-material-auto-complete-in-formarray?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)** . I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

```
npm install --save @angular/animations@6.0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, but my main problem is that I am not able to apply filter to the itemName and service inputs