# mat-autocomplet binded inside mat-table has an issue - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-autocomplete, mat-table

I have bind mat-autocomplete control (almost 30k records ) inside mat-table.
Here user is allowed to change values in auto complete and save the mat - table.

If user choose any different values in auto complete control in multiple rows of the mat-table and save.

If we re-bind the mat-table all the mat-autocomplete selected items are showing  with last value from the mat-autocomplete.

But here the data source object is updated properly.

Update and Save values in mat-autocomplete
[image]

After refreshing the Mat-table setting last value. [ Here the data source is fine, json object having correct values ]

[image]

### Html Code

```
<div class="ScrollStyle">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <!-- MaterialDescription Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Gedis Class">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Gedis Class</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.GedisClassCode}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- ItemClass Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ItemClass">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item Class </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

          <mat-autocomplete #sfAuto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="element.ItemClassId = $event.option.viewValue" [displayWith]="valueMapper">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let sf of filteredlistOfItemClass" [value]="sf.ItemClassId">
              {{sf.ItemClassId}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
            <input matInput placeholder="NA000" #sfInput [formControl]="itemClassControl" [matAutocomplete]="sfAuto"
                   (input)="itemClassOnChange($event.target.value)">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" [ngClass]="mat-header-cell"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

Typescript Code
---------------
  itemClassOnChange(val) {

    this.filteredlistOfItemClass = [];
    const value = val;
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    if (filterValue && !'') {
      this.filteredlistOfItemClass = this.listOfItemClass.filter(
        x =>
          `${x.ItemClassId}`.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue) 
      );
      this.sfInputTrigger.openPanel();
    }
  }

  //Used for binding selected Item class to the Itemclass auto suggest control
  public valueMapper = (key) => {
    let selection = this.filteredlistOfItemClass.find(e => e.ItemClassId === key);
    if (selection)
      return selection.ItemClassId;
    else
      return "NA000";
  };
}
```

The mat-table is placed in container  and it is placed in tab control, on click of tab page we are loading and binding the mat-table

Comment: You probably need to extend and create your own datasource and handle the data changes yourself. The default datasource does not handle changes like that very well from my experience.

Comment: Hi Ho Wei Lip, Thanks for reply.  But my the data source is updated fine. even it shows same value in all the mat-autocomplete  after refresh the data source is still correct

Comment: please create a demo slackblitz so everyone can understand your issue more easier

Comment: I don't know if this is gonna help, but I have used mat-auto-complete inside regular html table before, and I think it's pretty much the same idea here. 
take a look at this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562889/10121188
also, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szxkme?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html

Comment: Still I struck on the issue, The problem is whenever I rebind the Grid (Mat-table) my all mat-autocomplete updated with latest value in the last control.   So If each row in my mat-autocomplete is 'AAA','BBB', 'CCC' whenever I re bind the grid it is showing 'CCC','CCC',"CCC'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved by using Reactive form.
Create a FormGroup -> FormArray (mat-table) -> FormControlName to the input element.