# How to implement Material Autocomplete for the form field of formarray inside of formgroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on Angular 6. I have a `formGroup` with a `formArray`. The fields of `formArray` can be added dynamically. I need to add Material Autocomplete for a form field of `formArray`. It's not happening. I followed [How to use mat-autocomplete (Angular Material Autocomplete) inside FormArray (Reactive Forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562826/how-to-use-mat-autocomplete-angular-material-autocomplete-inside-formarray-re) this. However, it does not work. When value changes in `formField`, does not trigger the function.

```js
export interface IBrand {
    BrandId: string;
    BrandName: string;
}
//.......................
brandDatas: Observable<IBrand[]>[] = [];
bran: IBrand[] = [
    { "BrandId": "1234", "BrandName": "Apple" },
    { "BrandId": "12344", "BrandName": "Samsung" },
    { "BrandId": "12345", "BrandName": "Oppo" },
    { "BrandId": "12347", "BrandName": "Sony" },
    { "BrandId": "12349", "BrandName": "Panasonic" },

]

this.formGroup = this.fb.group({

    PurchaseDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    BillNo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    TotalCash: new FormControl(''),
    Total: new FormControl(''),
    ProductInformation: this.fb.array([
});

ngOnInit() {
    const productInformation = this.fb.group({
        ProductCategoryId: [''],
        BrandId: [''],
        ProductId: [''],
    })
    this.multipleform.push(productInformation);
    this.totalValue = 0;
    this.ManageNameControl(0);
}

ManageNameControl(index: number) {
    var arrayControl = this.formGroup.get('ProductInformation') as FormArray;
    let item = arrayControl.at(index);

    this.brandDatas[index] = item.get('BrandId').valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this._filterBrand(value))
        );
}

_filterBrand(name: string): IBrand[] {
    return this.bran.filter(opt =>
        opt.BrandName.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()));
}

displayBrand(brand?: IBrand): string | undefined {
    return brand ? brand.BrandName : undefined;
}
```

Inside html

```html
<div formArrayName="ProductInformation">
    <div *ngFor="let productInformation of multipleform.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
       ...
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="12%">
          <input [formControl]="BrandCtrl" matInput placeholder="Brand"
                     [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="BrandId" minlength="3" />
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayBrand">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brandDatas[i] | async" [value]="brand">
                  <span>{{brand.BrandName}}</span>
               </mat-option>
             </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

On debugging, the `ManageNameControl` function is invoked at first and when the form field is dynamically added and the valueChanges triggers at that time only. After that, valueChanges does not trigger on changing text on Brand field. How can this problem be solved? How can this sort of materail autocomplete be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template reference must be unique in you document. In your case the `MatAutocomplete` can be reused because it has the same functionality. If you put your `MatAutocomplete` outside your `ngFor` loop it should work.

```
<div formArrayName="ProductInformation">
    <div *ngFor="let productInformation of multipleform.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
       ...
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="12%">
          <input [formControl]="BrandCtrl" matInput placeholder="Brand"
                     [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="BrandId" minlength="3" /
          </mat-form-field>
       ...
    </div>
</div>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayBrand">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brandDatas[i] | async" [value]="brand">
       <span>{{brand.BrandName}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while mat-auto-complete inside for loop.

Move your forloop code to separate component and keep formgroup as input to the component. Then call the new component from ngFor and pass the formgroup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813