# Angular 9 how to use debouncetime for input change event (keyup)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular9

How to use debounce time for searching data in API's for keyup input change event.
Give a look at the following code. It is not working. A search request to API is made on every input change. 
I want to make a search request to API using some denounce time.

Thank you in advance

.html

```
 <input matInput (keyup) ="Onsearchinput($event.target.value)">
```

.ts

```
Onsearchinput(value){

    debounceTime(500)

    console.log(value)

      this.productService.search_Products(value).subscribe(data => {
        if(data){
          console.log(data)
          this.product_list = data
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Have you even tried to search for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777621/3375906

Comment: The problem is I am using this inside formArray. So I can't write code in constructor or ngOninit or ngAfterviewinit. And If I use debounce time in keyup event, search operation is occuring for every input change

Comment: Then you show the complete code for the formArray. Otherwise, we won't know what is your difficulty.

Comment: it's relationed with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A form control will expose the changes in its values as an observable named `valueChanges`. You're going to need to use the `pipe` operator, piping `valueChanges` into it. You can't just call `debounceTime` like you are doing above.

You're also going to want to use something like a `switchMap` to ensure that any in-flight requests are cancelled if a user types something while a request is in progress.

Without seeing your code this is the best I can really do.

Try using a formControl.

html;

`<input matInput [formControl]='myControl'>`

In your ts, declare this as a class variable:

`myControl = new FormControl();`

Then pipe the changes from it like this (can go in `ngOnInit`):

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
   debounceTime(500),
   switchMap(changedValue => this.productService.search_Products(changedValue)),
).subscribe(productList => this.product_list = productList);
```