# How to prevent previous chosen values in dropdowns from clearing? I am using MatSelectSearch in a FormArray

Tags: angular, select, angular-material, dropdown, formarray

I'm trying to implement the MatSelectSearch in our dropdowns inside a FormArray. I think I'm almost there, but the issue I'm having is after choosing a value for my first row, I add another row and start searching again, the value of the first row seems clearing until I'm finished typing or chosen a value for the second row.

I've made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mhyl4o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.html) to demo my issue.

Thanks ahead for any help!

Comment: you has an unique "filter_admin_advocacy" but you need an array of them. This SO is about mat-autocomplete, but the same technique can use in MatSelectSearch:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813

Comment: @Eliseo hi, sorry I just replied now I was trying to figure out the SO you linked and applied the concept to mine. But to be honest I am failry new to angular and I'm not sure how to continue. I forked a stackblitz from my original: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mhyl4o-skmqhf

Comment: I add a detail answer (I use your first stackblitz) Yesterday I was in hurry, I hope this was more clearer

Comment: okay thank you very much, I'm really stuck for 2 days now with this sadly.

Comment: @Eliseo I've accepted your answer and it really does solve it. I have one question though, I'm trying to apply this in the edit. In the edit form, we show the values saved from db back to the fields. my problem is showing the chosen value when everything is loaded. the value's id is there. but I have to click the dropdown field for it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving my comment.

First declare filter_admin_advocacy as array

```
//see that is simple an empty array
public filter_admin_advocacy: ReplaySubject<any[]>[] = [];
```

Change the function initializeAdminAdvocacyFilter. We use this function to give value to this.filter_admin_advocancy[i]

Futhermore, we using "startWith" pipe to force the next -else at first we get an empty list-

```
initializeAdminAdvocacyFilter(i) {
    //declare the filter_admin_advocacy[i]
    this.filter_admin_advocacy[i] = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);

    const adminAdvocacy = <FormArray>this.type.controls['selected_interests'];
    adminAdvocacy.controls[i].get('admin_advocacy_filter_ctrl').valueChanges
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this._onDestroy),
      //it's important the startWith
      startWith(adminAdvocacy.controls[i].get('admin_advocacy_filter_ctrl').value))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.filterAdminAdvocacies(i);
    });
  }
```

The filterAdminAdvocacies function, we replace the this.filter_admin_advocacy by this.filter_admin_advocacy[i]

```
filterAdminAdvocacies(i) {
    if(!this.advocacies) {
      return;
    }

    // get the search keyword
    const adminAdvocacy = <FormArray>this.type.controls['selected_interests'];

    let search = adminAdvocacy.controls[i].get('admin_advocacy_filter_ctrl').value;

    if(!search) {
      //HERE
      this.filter_admin_advocacy[i].next(this.advocacies.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }

    // filter the gender_titles
    //and HERE
    this.filter_admin_advocacy[i].next(
      this.advocacies.filter(advocacies => advocacies.advocacy.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );

  }
```

In ngOnInit, after initializeForm, call to initializeAdminAdvocacyFilter(0)

```
  this.initializeForm();
  this.initializeAdminAdvocacyFilter(0)

  //and remove the this.filter_admin_advocacy.next
  //the startWith in the subscribe make the work 
  //    this.filter_admin_advocacy[0].next(this.advocacies.slice());
```

The last use the array in the filter

```
  <mat-option *ngFor="let advocacy of filter_admin_advocacy[i] | async" 
       [value]="advocacy.id">
       {{ advocacy.advocacy }}
  </mat-option>
```

I [forked the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mhyl4o-tzfzlx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexamples%2F01-single-selection-example%2Fsingle-selection-example.component.html)

Comment: oh my god thank you very much for this! Um I will test it after an hour, have to attend a mass. But this surely will help! Thank you very much!