# How to create rows of mat-autocomplete elements in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete

I am building an angular app. In the template I have button, on clicking this it adds new autocomplete element. But problem arises when I select an option, I see other auto complete shows the previously filtered value. I filter method and form control is common for all the autocomplete elements. I am trying to figure out, how to make the formelement and filter method unique for each auto complete element.

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code snippet,

**template.html**

```
<button (click)="addelement()"> Add New Elemnt </button>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let name of names; let j = index">
    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </ng-container>
```

**template.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Display value autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-display-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-display-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-display-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    {name: 'Mary'},
    {name: 'Shelley'},
    {name: 'Igor'}
  ];

  names=[{}]

  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user: User): string {
    return user && user.name ? user.name : '';
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  addelement() {
    this.names.push({});
  }
}
```

In the code snippet above you will 'names' array, based on the object pushed to this array, autocomplete will appear in the template. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz where your problem is reproduced?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyfpfx

Comment: I added array of mat autocomplete elements , I want them to be independent of each other selection and filtering options