# Angular nestead form with n autocompletes inputs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, nested-forms

I working with `Angular 9` and I have a nested form like this:

```
createFormGroup() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    Id: new FormControl(0),
    Name: new FormControl(''),
    Children: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        Id: new FormControl(0),
        Autocomplete: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      })
    ])
  })
}
```

I need to access this n `Autocomplete` for subscribe events and show recommendations.

Normally I access with this when have one control

```
this.filteredData = this.myform.controls['Autocomplete'].valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith < string | any > (''),
  map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
  map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.mylist.slice())
);
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503425/angular-9-formarray-search-operation-executing-for-only-first-dynamic-control/61519813#61519813

Answer (score 0):

you have nested form, Autocomplete is inside FormArray that inside FormGroup:

```
{  
Id: 0
Name: ""
Children: [
  {
   Autocomplete: ""
   Id: 0 }
 ]
}
```

So for getting the Autocomplete FormControl:

```
let autocompleteFormControl =((form.controls["Children"]).controls[0]).controls["Autocomplete"];
autocompleteFormControl.valueChanges...
```

Comment: you right ray j, but users can add and "n" quantity of child, then this need working for n autocomplete input into FormArray

Comment: get the formArray:  form.controls["Children"].controls, and for each element : e.controls["Autocomplete"].valueChanges.....